# Gitlab CI/CD - is it possible to execute a PowerShell script block as a different user?

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

In my CI/CD pipeline, I need to execute some PowerShell script under a different Windows user account, so I've done this via a PS script which does the following:

```
    $scriptBlock = {
      $userName = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
      return $result + "`r`n`nJob username is $userName"
    }

    $job = Start-Job -Name 'Test' -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -Credential $credential
    $null = Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout 120
    $jobResult = Receive-Job -Job $job

    $r = $jobResult

    Write-Verbose $r
```

The $credential variable is already correctly assigned with the alternate username/password and the script works when executing it locally on my machine but not if running in the GitLab pipeline.  The error I get is:

```
[localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' with working directory 'C:\GitlabRunner'. The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it..
```

Is it possible to execute script in a CI/CD as a user other than the one under which the GitLab runner is executing?